# P0171 code with high fuel trim

Tags: toyota, corolla, p0171

I have a 2001 Toyota Corolla.

Lately it has been throwing the P0171 code (system too lean). My short term fuel trim is normal at idle. +/- 5 % at idle and long term fuel trim is high at idle +18 %.

When I rev the engine to 1500 rpm the short term stays the same and long term fuel trim goes down to about 14%. Weird thing is when I drive the car, the short term fuel trim is normal and the long term goes down to 7 percent or so, BUT intermittently at around 2200 to 2500 rpm the short term shoots up to around 25 percent and long term fuel trim goes to 35 %. This is the point where I throw the P0171 code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd start with vacuum leaks - especially inspect the intake hose(s) and look for cracks.  This could be a "false air" or "unmetered air" issue.

Comment: Jake, are you accelerating when the STFT spikes?

Comment: Thank you, SteveRacer, this is what i was thinking also. And Zaid, yes i believe i was accelerating when the stft spikes. I would have to check. It only does this once every few miles though. And the engine load was 35 percent when my computer threw the code